# How to display subscribers in list using api(MailChimp) using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, json, api, android-studio, android-asynctask

i have diplayed the list name in logcat, but i am having difficulty in retreiving subscribers in list  which i made in the mailChimp

what would be the perfect way to do this using AsyncTask?

thanks!

```
 public class FetchLists extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<MailChimpList>> {


        @Override
        protected List<MailChimpList> doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            int count = params[0];
            int offset = params[1];

            String urlString = "https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists?apikey=..............";
            urlString = urlString + "&count=" + count + "&offset=" + offset;

            List<MailChimpList> listTitles = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                String line = reader.readLine();
                String response = "";
                while(line != null){
                    response += line;
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

                int itemCount = object.getInt("total_items");
                Log.d("ashu", "total item count is " + itemCount);




                JSONArray lists = object.getJSONArray("lists");


                for (int i = 0; i < lists.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject listData = (JSONObject) lists.get(i);
                    MailChimpList mailChimpList = new MailChimpList();
                    mailChimpList.id = listData.getString("id");
                    mailChimpList.title = listData.getString("name");

 JSONObject contact = listData.getJSONObject("contact");
                mailChimpList.emailId=contact.getJSONArray("lists/{list_id}/members");
                    listTitles.add(mailChimpList);
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         Log.d("codekamp",  listTitles.get(1).id.toString());

        Log.d("codekamp",listTitles.get(1).title.toString());

        Log.d("codekamp",listTitles.get(1).emailId.toString());

            return listTitles;
        }


    }
```

i want to retreive the list of all subscribers for a particular listname which are stored in it!

error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                  Process: in.codekamp.asynctaskdemo, PID: 17134
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
                      at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                      at in.codekamp.asynctaskdemo.FetchLists.doInBackground(FetchLists.java:74)
                      at in.codekamp.asynctaskdemo.FetchLists.doInBackground(FetchLists.java:21)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: What's the error or incorrect value you are getting?

Comment: no there is no error i don't how to sought out the listnames particularly?

Comment: Can you share you JSON?

Comment: no i am not getting any

Comment: In your debugger what does your listData consists of?

Comment: Is the error stack related to the code at all? I don't see a line 74 in your `FetchLists` at all

Comment: in mailchimp i have created 6 list named differently i want to fetch all the list in a array at a same time.......but i can only fetch one at a time  help me to resolve this

Comment: You have empty lists... You cannot get(1) from an empty list. Check your JSON data

Comment: I tried to get the JSON from the link you posted but that seems to throw an error cuz of my geolocation. Your list is coming back empty so check the contents of the response.

Answer (score 1):

i have written some code to help you get the response

```
 String urlString = "https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists?apikey=efb91redfef1215rac5rff4c8sdsfsf8a77-us11";
        urlString = urlString + "&count=" + count + "&offset=" + offset;

        List<String> listTitles = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            String response = "";
            while(line != null){
                response += line;
                line = reader.readLine();
            }

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

            int itemCount = object.getInt("total_items");
            Log.d("ashu", "total item count is " + itemCount);




            JSONArray lists = object.getJSONArray("lists");


            for (int i = 0; i < lists.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject listData = (JSONObject) lists.get(i);
                String id= listData.getString("id");
                String title = listData.getString("name");

                JSONObject contact = listData.getJSONObject("contact");
                JSONArray list=contact.getJSONArray("lists");

                JSONObject contactdata = list.getJSONObject(0);
                String  company=contactdata.getString("student");


                JSONArray links = object.getJSONArray("_links");
                for(int j=0;j<=links.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject linkobjects = (JSONObject) links.get(i);
                    String relevance=linkobjects.getString("rel");
                    Log.d("rel", ""+relevance);
                }
                Log.d("id", ""+id);
                Log.d("name", ""+title);
                Log.d("cmpny", ""+company);
              listTitles.add(mailChimpList);}
```

from this you can understand the code and you can store in your list. hope it helps.

Comment: plz provide json response

Comment: so what you want from that response

Comment: in mailchimp i have created 6 list named differently i want to fetch all the list in a array at a same time.......but i can only fetch one at a time that's my problem

Comment: what the 2nd loop is for?

Comment: in your json response _links is an array which contains no. of objects for that